# How do i add toolbar for android in xamarin,forms as ToolbarItem is not working for .droid?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uitoolbaritem

I want to have a toolbar for my mobile application in xamarin.forms. I surfed throught the net and got to know about toolbaritems but i think it just works  for the windows phone not for android. Any help regarding this issue would is heartly appreciated.
Ps: I need a toolbar in the tabbed pages also.

Here is my piece of code:

```
//main page

namespace eSewaXamarin
{

public class App:Application

{

public App ()

{   
        MainPage =  new TabbedPageClass ();
    }

    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep ()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }


}
}

//tabbed page

namespace eSewaXamarin
{

public class TabbedPageClass: TabbedPage

{

public TabbedPageClass ()

{

    //this.SwipeEnabled = true;

    ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Click", null, () => {

    Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
            }));
            //this.Title = "eSewa";
            //TabbedPageClass tabbedPage=new TabbedPageClass();

            this.Children.Add (new MainMenu ());
            this.Children.Add (new QuickMenu ());
            this.Children.Add (new AboutPage ());


        }

    }
}

//about page

namespace eSewaXamarin
{

public class AboutPage:ContentPage

{

public AboutPage(){

Title="About";

this.BackgroundColor = Colors.lightGrey;


Padding = new Thickness (0,Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0),0,0);

            var listView = new ListView ();
            listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(AboutCell));
            listView.ItemsSource = AboutClass.getAboutText ();


            listView.RowHeight = 80;
            var fonePayIcon = new Image{ 
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,


            };
            fonePayIcon.Source = ImageSource.FromFile ("footer_logo.png");
            this.Content = new ScrollView {
                Content = new StackLayout{
                    Children={listView,new StackLayout{
                            Padding=new Thickness(0,8,0,8),
                            BackgroundColor=Color.FromHex ("dfdfdf"),
                            VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                            Children={fonePayIcon}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }; 



            listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
                if (e.SelectedItem != null) {

                    AboutClass aboutClass=(AboutClass)e.SelectedItem;
                    int id=aboutClass.id;
                    AppLog.showlog ("Selected item:::::" + aboutClass.id);
                    if(id==0){
                        Navigation.PushModalAsync (new NavigationPage(new Registration()));
                    }else if(id==1){
                        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new AbouteSewa()));
                    }else if(id==2){
                        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AboutFonePay());
                    }else if(id==3){
                        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AboutSecurityTips());
                    }else if(id==4){
                        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AboutAppInfo());
                    }
                }
                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

            };



        }
    }

}

//registration page


namespace eSewaXamarin
{

public class Registration: ContentPage

{

public Registration ()

{


    this.Title="Registration";

            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Click", null, () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
            }));

            this.BackgroundColor = Colors.lightGrey;
            var label = new Label {
                Text = Strings.eSewaRegistratinAbout,
                Style=Styles.LabelStyle
            };

            var registerButton=new Button{
                Text="Register",
                Style= Styles.buttonStyleGrey
            };

            var esewa_icon = new Image {
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,

            };
            esewa_icon.Source = ImageSource.FromFile ("header_logo.png");

            Content = new StackLayout {

                Style = Styles.toolbarStyle,
                Children = {new StackLayout{
                        Style=Styles.stackLayoutStyleForAboutSection,
                        Children={label,registerButton}}
                }
            };

            registerButton.Clicked+=delegate{
                var SmsTask = MessagingPlugin.SmsMessenger;

                if (SmsTask.CanSendSms)


                SmsTask.SendSms("9801063628", "hello aqhtar ");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What code do you have that works on Windows Phone but not Android? Are your working in XAML or from the code-behind? Please provide some code and more detail of what you are trying to do before we can effectively help you :)

Comment: i edited the post with code. Please have a look. Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Add this to your `Page` **constructor**:

  ```net
  ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Click", null, () => {
      Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
  }));
  ```
- Make sure you're using the newest version of Xamarin.Forms. It works just fine.
- Wrap your `MainPage` inside `NavigationPage`:

  ```net
  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourHomePage());
  ```

Comment: i had used it before too and tried it today as well but the toolbar is still not showing itself up. Any other ways to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you have the newest version of Xamarin.Forms? Is you main page a NavigationPage? I edited my answer

Comment: i actually have a tabbed page as the main page. And the above mentioned content page is called from one of the tabbed page.Does having a tabbed page as mainpage has anything to do with the toolbar.and regarding version of xamarin.forms, yes i have the newest version of xamarin.forms. I have edited my post with whole switch of pages in my application.

Comment: i ran a clean build with my project and its working fine now. I am so much thankful to you :)