# Can't add ToolbarItem to ContentPage

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I declare my main page:

```
public App () {
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

Then on main page open `ContantPage` after tapping a button:

```
class MainPage : ContentPage {
    public MainPage() {
        button.Clicked += to_my_contentpage;
        //...
    }

    private async void to_my_contentpage(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new my_contentpage());
        //using PushAsync doesn't help
    }
}
```

And try to show button on this page as `ToolbarItem`:

```
public class my_contentpage : ContentPage {
    public my_contentpage () {
        ToolbarItem AddButton = new ToolbarItem("AddButton", "AddIcon.png", () => {
            Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
        });
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem());
        //...
        this.Content = new StackLayout { Children = { header, listView } };
    }
}
```

I feel like doing everithing according to this answer but my `ToolbarItem` is not included to my page:
[How do i add toolbar for android in xamarin,forms as ToolbarItem is not working for .droid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437645/how-do-i-add-toolbar-for-android-in-xamarin-forms-as-toolbaritem-is-not-working)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When adding a `ToolBarItem` it is required to use a `NavigationPage`. Did you try doing `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new my_contentpage()));?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PushModalAsync is not going to work in this case, since you need to have a Navigation Bar in order to add `ToolBarItems` to it.

Since a Modal page explicitly does not show/contain a NavigationBar you are not going to be able to do it this way.

Solutions:

1. Create a Custom NavigationBar and add any Views you need to it.
2. Do not use a Modal Page.

Hope this helps.